# Problem with assembly loading in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, assemblies, loading

I have got two projects in my solution: Silverlight and standard one. The standard one references System.Xml assembly (version 4.0.0.0), however the Silverlight one references System.Xml assembly (v. 2.0.5.0). I want to make an instance of XmlWriter in my Silverlight project. Here comes the problem - the exception is thrown (file not found for System.Xml assembly). I believe it is a matter of different assembly versions.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue? Ive read something about the binding redirection - is it the key to the solution? If so, how to do this?

Thank you in advance for the reply!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I have resolved the issue. As I supposed, the DLL was confused with another library of the same name (from .NET 4.0). I had to use a Copy Local for System.Xml for Silverlight. Anyway, thanks!